# I've answered, but become aware I'm not able to answer the question

Tags: discussion, answers

What should I do when I have come to understand that I'm not able to give a correct answer or provide a solution to question I've already answered and discussed with the question's author?

1. Delete my answer
2. Tell author that I can't help them
3. Abandon the question leaving everything as it is currently

I'm looking from the perspective that everything in SO should be informative: what is the best way to resolve this situation?

Comment: I would say option #4: All of the above.

Comment: Good point by the way, but by quitting I meant quitting without noticing author neither deleting question

Comment: I have deleted my answer whenever I feel that on average, a StackOverflow user reading it has not benefitted by my answer.  Even if I can not provide an answer useful to the OP, I sometimes leave my answer, if I believe it has value.  If it is heavily downvoted, that usually prompts me to delete it completely, as my own internal Usefulness Sensors have then apparently malfunctioned.

Comment: Delete your answer. Keep an eye on the question, you may learn something. If comments have become obsolete, there is a flag for that if you click on the little flag icon to the left of a comment. Your own comments you can always delete anytime, with absolute impunity.

Comment: I've done a bit of an edit. Don't be down on yourself for trying. It's good to try, and making mistakes, but realising it, and doing something about it, is a great way to learn. If you don't like the edit, just roll it back :-)

Comment: Depends if it's usefully wrong, or just wrong. A partial answer is better than no answer, and is sometimes all you can give.

Comment: @TinyGiant, If you do 1 or 2, or both, you obviously don't do 3, right?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye That was a hyperbole, but it could be loosely interpreted as: "*Delete the answer, possibly leave a comment saying you cannot help, then abandon the question.*"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Simply deleting the answer is sufficient. If you feel the need to explain why you deleted the answer you can leave a comment for the OP.

As a side note this is a good reason to [make sure you have the details before posting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem). If you need more info to understand the question, ask for it before you answer.

Comment: Leaving "I don't know" comments is not helpful, it's noise. So just delete your answer.  Don't feel bad.   You tried, and your mind and your manners were all in good working order.

Comment: @WarrenP that's what I've thought about informativeness of SO

Comment: @WarrenP I get where you're coming from, in these cases it's a good idea to go back and delete/cleanup the comments after a few minutes.

Comment: Just thinking that sometimes explaining the misunderstanding can help the OP to further clarify the question... "Sorry I thought you were trying to foo the bar, not baz the foo, I've deleted my answer..."

Comment: There is a great VTC options called "Unclear what you are asking".

Comment: I think leaving a comment below _your_ answer can be useful (Prior to deletion) can be useful, because 10k+ readers can see it.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that it depends.

If you answer is plain wrong because you did not understand what was the actual question and answered another problem, or if there are better answers, you should just leave a comment saying why the answer should be deleted, wait some time for OP to read the comment (between 1 hour and 1 day) and delete the answer.

But if the question was simply too hard and your answer add information for future readers (at least *seemed promising but no luck*), or partially answers the question but not in totality **and there are no better answers**, you should keep it. I would add a disclaimer above the answer, something like *This is only a partial answer but is the best I can do* and add a comment explaining OP why you abandon.

The reason behind it, is that even if it does not fully answers OP's question, if you think that it add value, you should keep it. A good indicator would be whether it has been upvoted (keep it) or downvoter (delete it).